# How can I combine two arrays into one by a common attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, each, polymorphic-associations

How can I combine two arrays into one so that for example...

```
Day 1: Notes/form
Day 2: Notes/form
Day 3: Notes/form
Day 4: Notes/form
Day 5: Notes/form
```

If a user then creates a note on Day 3 it would look like...

```
Day 1: Notes/form
Day 2: Notes/form
Day 3: Notes/notes
Day 4: Notes/form
Day 5: Notes/form
```

The code monstrosity below tried to achieve the above, but the iteration is all off. If for example a note is created on Day 1 and Day 3 then the output will look like...

```
Day 1: Notes/notes # Shows both Day 1 and Day 3 note. Only want to show Day 1 note
Day 1: Notes/form
Day 2: Notes/form
Day 2: Notes/form
Day 3: Notes/notes # Shows both Day 1 and Day 3 note. Only want to show Day 3 note
Day 3: Notes/form
Day 4: Notes/form
Day 4: Notes/form
Day 5: Notes/form
Day 5: Notes/form
```

**challenges/show**

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  <% @notes.each do |note| %>
    Day <%= i + 1 %>
    <% if note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
      <%= render 'notes/notes' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To recap, a user creates a challenge. A challenge has the attribute `days_challenged`. The user chooses how many days will be challenged, i.e. 10, 15, 30, etc. For each of those days I want to show a notes/form. If the user then input a note on a day then the notes/form should be replaced on the show page by that note (no day should have more than one note associated with it).

Comment: It seems like you might be using the wrong data structure for this... have you considered using a hash?

Comment: I can't figure out how to integrate it. You mean like adding into the controller something like `notes_for_date = @notes.group_by(&:note_date)`? I can't get it to work in the view though @photoionized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing too much inside the loop that you're using to find the day's note. This should be about right:

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  Day <%= i + 1 %>
  <% if @notes.any? { |note| note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") } %>
    <%= render 'notes/notes' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is still too much logic in the view.

1. As photoionized commented, it would be easier if `@notes` were a `Hash` whose keys were `Date`s and whose values were `Notes`. You could then replace the `any?` with a hash lookup.
2. It's unclear to me why you need to compare `strftime("%m/%d/%y")`. You should just be able to compare `Date`s. (If you can't do that because they're in different time zones or something, consider fixing that -- it'll cause confusion all over your application.)
3. I'd extract `dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged)` into a method on `Challenge` named something like `current_dates_challenged` and use that in the view.

Comment: Awesome! This gets rid of the multi-rendering of the notes/form when multiple notes are created. Still shows multiple notes per day. So like on Day 1 a note for Day 1 and Day 3 is showing whereas only Day 1 note should show for that day. Maybe you could help guide me. In notes/notes I have `<% @notes.each do |note| %> <%= note.notes_text %> <% end %>`. In challenges_controller `def show` I have`@notable = @challenge @notes = @notable.notes @note = Note.new`.

Comment: Better [edit it in to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37012917/edit), or possibly ask a new one. It's too hard to follow stuffed in to a comment.

Comment: Alright Dave I made a new question :] Hopefully you can help me over here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013995/how-to-render-notes-who-note-note-date-date Thanks so much!