# How to render only notes that equal date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instead of showing all the notes per day, how can we only show one note per day, the note whose `note.note_date == date`?

```
Day 1: Notes/notes # Shows both Day 1 and Day 3 note. Only want to show Day 1 note
Day 2: Notes/form
Day 3: Notes/notes # Shows both Day 1 and Day 3 note. Only want to show Day 3 note
Day 4: Notes/form
Day 5: Notes/form
```

**challenges/show**

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  Day <%= i + 1 %>
  <% if @notes.any? { |note| note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") } %>
    <%= render 'notes/notes' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**notes/notes**

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <%= note.notes_text %>
<% end %>
```

**notes/form**

```
<%= form_for [@notable, @note] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :notes_text, placeholder: 'Enter Recap' %>
  <%= f.date_select :notes_date, selected: date, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
<% end %>
```

**challenges_controller**

```
def show
  @notable = @challenge
  @notes = @notable.notes
  @note = Note.new
end
```

To recap, a user creates a challenge. A challenge has the attribute `days_challenged`. The user chooses how many days will be challenged, i.e. 10, 15, 30, etc. For each of those days a `notes/form` will be rendered. If a `note.notes_date` equals a respective day then how can we only show that one note in place of `notes/form`?

Comment: Can you explain why the solution that you presented is not working?  Is there an error message or incorrect output that can be provided?  Edits to the question are better than replying in the comments.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MichaelGaskill. I didn't present a solution. I explained what I have, which is where every note is being rendered with `notes/notes`. I don't want every note to be rendered. I only want note  that equals `date` to be rendered on that respective day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% if @notes.any? 
  @today_notes = @notes.select{ |note| note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") } %>
  <%= render 'notes/notes' %>
<% else %>
...
<% end %>
```

Then use `@today_notes` in the notes/notes partial.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Just figured it out but your answer is more concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<%= render 'notes/notes' %>` partial to below one, and follow right below note.html.erb file.

**Challenges Show:**

```
    <%= render partial: 'notes/notes', locals:{note: note} %>
```

Rename note.html.erb to underscore `_notes.html.erb`

**notes/_notes.html.erb:**

```
  <%= note.notes_text %>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question asked by OP?

Comment: What u didnt like it ? i though, he tries to use that note through partial. also, as i see he's updated the question.